# Update XML using Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, dom

I would like to update XML's node dataset child value and unit as well using DOM or Javascript .

Pl suggest me how can i do it

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<JSChart>
    <dataset type="line">
        <data unit="10" value="2"/>
        <data unit="15" value="9"/>
        <data unit="18" value="2"/>
        <data unit="19" value="6"/>
        <data unit="20" value="8.5"/>
        <data unit="25" value="10"/>
        <data unit="30" value="9"/>
        <data unit="35" value="8"/>
        <data unit="40" value="5"/>
        <data unit="45" value="1"/>
        <data unit="50" value="50"/>
    </dataset>
    <optionset>

        <option set="setBackgroundImage" value="'chart_bg.jpg'"/>
    </optionset>
</JSChart>
```

PL send me code. 
thanks in advance

Comment: Kindly tell us what you have done so far.

Comment: what is ur expected output ?